# LinkedIn Jobs APIs details

Tags: linkedin-api

I represent an organization. we are building mobile app for students and would like to know if there is a way to integrate linked-in job postings to our APP. If any REST APIs exposed around that feature then would like to get more details about those APIs.

We are looking for following feature:
- Get the job posting from linked-in API.
- Search or Filter them.
- Provide an option to the user to apply for such posting.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
LinkedIn has updated its API and I couldn't find any information related to getting LinkedIn Jobs in LinkedIn's new API. According to [this Zapier post](https://zapier.com/blog/updates/439/linkedin-triggers-and-actions-being-removed), Zapier is removing triggers related to New Jobs because of the API changes. In addition, Zapier [removed all integrations related to creating, getting, or updating LinkedIn Jobs](https://zapier.com/apps/linkedin/integrations).

***In other words, LinkedIn has removed the ability to get job postings from the LinkedIn Rest API.***

**OLD ANSWER:**
I just finished up customizing a WordPress Plugin that currently gets LinkedIn Company Updates to now get LinkedIn Company job postings from the LinkedIn REST API.

The key API call for you to make would be the following:
`GET: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/updates?format=json`

*IMPORTANT*: Make sure to set the event-type parameter to job-posting when making your GET request.

There is more information on all of the parameters for this endpoint at https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_profile.