# Is it possible to get Job listings with Linked API v2?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm looking through the docs for LinkedIn v2 API and cannot find any information on how to get jobs listings - search jobs. If it's possible, my questions would be:

1. What authentication is required to get job listings?
2. Does it require any special review by LinkedIn to get job listings? If yes, where can I apply?
3. Where can I find more information about the API endpoints?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think LinkedIn gives such an API as v2. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54299692/linkedin-api-v2-possible-to-get-company-job-listings , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57690512/api-job-search-v2-documentation-linkedin and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43949076/linkedin-jobs-apis-details